# jQuery when all elements have a class do something

Tags: jquery

I have any number of elements on a page with a class of choice e.g.

```
<div class="choice"></div>
<div class="choice"></div>
```

When I run a function it adds a class of done to the the div so they become:

```
<div class="choice done"></div>
```

Within this same function each time it runs I'm then going to check how many of those choices have the class of done on them and when they all have it I'm going to run another function.

This is what I have done so far:

```
function addDone(element) {

$num = 0;

$(element).addClass('done');

$('.choice').each(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('done')) {
        $num + 1;
    }
});

if($num >= $('.choice').length) {
    alert('all done...');
}

}
```

But it runs the alert as soon as I call the function... so not working properly, any ideas on what the problem is or better solutions to do this?

**Note: That in the real app each choice has an id when is what goes in place of the element variable used in the function!**

Comment: that was just a typo on here!

Comment: @Cameron How about doing a length comparison of `.done` and `.choice`, instead of doing `.hasClass` on each `.done`. Something like `if($('.choice').length == $('.done').length) { alert('All done'); }`. Better if it inside a wrapper

Comment: is $num += 1; prefered over  $num + 1;?  I think your num variable won't increment.  However, is your html and class names correct? I can't see why the num variable would be greater than length of the 'choice' elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could rephrase this as:

> do something when there are no elements with `choice` but without `done`

In which case, the following is a little neater:

```
if (!$(".choice").not(".done").length) {
    alert("all done");
}
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stevegreatrex/NVHXm/)

Answer (score 2):

```
$num + 1;
```

should probably be

```
$num = $num + 1;
```

Apart from that there may be better solutions as others have suggested.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!$(".choice:not(.done)").length)
    // do your magic here.
```

Comment: `.choice:not(.choice)` will always return an empty set - presumably you meant `.choice:not(.done)`